# Need to access <input> data from a <form>, that has been appended with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have an admin page where I add and delete table rows on the fly. 
The page comes loaded with the existent data in the database (mostly consisting in a sku_code and 5 different prices) but when I add rows on the fly, and fill them with the corresponding skus and prices, I want to save them as well in the database.

The problem is that what I do on the client-side with Javascript (add table rows on the fly) with `innerHTML = '<input type="text">` is not accesible via `$_POST` variables of the main `<form>`

So basically i add via Javascript 's so i can fill them and save them as well in the database. But the $_POST values are empty.
Javascript code works fine. I have no clue where should i start debugging.

here's some Javascript code i'm using

```
function insert_record(){

    var my_table = document.getElementById('my_table')
    var tr = my_table.insertRow(my_table.rows.length-1)
    //id-ul curent, numar toate row-urile - 1 (care este butonul OK)

    var c_id = my_table.rows.length-2

        tr.id = 'row_' + c_id + ''
    var tr_td_1 = tr.insertCell(0)
        tr_td_1.className = 'text2'
        tr_td_1.align = 'center'
        tr_td_1.innerHTML = 'SKU'
    var tr_td_2 = tr.insertCell(1)  
        tr_td_2.className = 'text3'
        tr_td_2.width = '63'
        tr_td_2.innerHTML = '<input name="sku_' + c_id + '" type="text" id="sku_' + c_id + '" size="33" value="">'
```

....this addes a  inside the table just before the last  which contains the  submit button, after which there's the

Comment: Are you sure the fields are inside a form? It should work without a problem

Comment: Could you please share your code? Ideally it should work.

Comment: Start debugging by checking your field names and your php validation and INSERT/UPDATE commands.

Comment: first of all you shall show us some code so we can reproduce this problem.

Comment: `innerHTML = '<input type="text">` Will have no effect in your POST as it has no field name.

Comment: Perhaps you should get the data from the inputs via JavaScript, then send it via AJAX instead of relying on the submit button of the form for $_POST variables.

Comment: and also you can `var_dump($_POST)` to check if all fields are there, if not, your new `<input>` element is not inside the form

Comment: Daniel is right: make sure they're appended to the form element, and don't forget to _set the name attribute_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a label to element. Then you can grab it in next page.

Instead of `innerHTML = <input type="text">` try to use

```
<script>
      function addElement(tag_type, target, parameters) {
        //Create element
        var newElement = document.createElement(tag_type);

        //Add parameters
        if (typeof parameters != 'undefined') {
          for (parameter_name in parameters) {
            newElement.setAttribute(parameter_name, parameters[parameter_name]);
          }
        }

        //Append element to target
        document.getElementById(target).appendChild(newElement);
      }
    </script>
```

You can call this function below either click of even or manually `addElement('INPUT','targetTag',{id:'my_input_tag', name:'my_input_tag', type:'text', size:'5'});`

Comment: this approach works same as what i was using, but it seems totally clearer than what i'm using...so i'll use this...but it seems i still have problems with getting $_POST vars...i'll try debug the code some more and get back here if i have something...thanks

Comment: :))))))) my bad....the first <form> tag was not above the TABLE on which I was doing Javascript inserts and stuff....i moved the <form> tag to encapsulate the <table> and now it started to work :) weee :) thanks guys....i'll keep in mind to create smoother DOM tree with appendChild, instead of always using innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

you should give the name attribute. if you are worried about the unlimited numbers of fields just go for the array of the input variables,

like this

```
<input type="text" name="field1[]">
```

Now you can access them in post like this:

```
$_POST['field1']  //this is an array of fields
```

**EDIT:**

First thing is that you should use some library like jquery which eases the work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make sure your all your fields are inside the `form` and that you have **named**  all of them instead of trying `ajax` or functions like @shail suggested.

In  my opinion they are not solving the problem, just avoiding it.